# ¿porque React me devuelve not found cuando le paso la ruta con el id de la pelicula?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un Link con una ruta a to `= {/movies/${id}}` pero me lleva a la página de *not found*; ¿A que se debe esto?... estoy usando un *template* con *backticks*, solo no se muestran no se por que.

Al hacer clic en el *link* que hace de botón me lleva a la ruta *not found* en vez de llevarme al formulario donde se cargan las películas.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class MovieCard extends Component {
    render() { 
        const { title, movieImg, genre, id } = this.props.movie;

        if(movieImg) {
            return ( 
                <article>
                    <div className="card my-4">
                        <img src = {movieImg} 
                        width = "920" height = "524" alt = "" className = "img-fluid card-img-top" />
                        <div className="card-body text-center">
                            <h5>{title}</h5>
                            <p>{genre.name}</p>
                        </div>
                        <Link to = {`/movies/${id}`} className="btn btn-primary mb-3 width">
                            Change Image
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </article>
             );
        } else if (movieImg === "") {
            return ( 
                <article>
                    <div className="card my-4">
                        <img src = "https://github.com/Ceci007/images/blob/master/img-vidly/image-default.jpg?raw=true"
                        width = "920" height = "524" alt = "" className = "img-fluid card-img-top" />
                        <div className="card-body text-center">
                            <h5>{title}</h5>
                            <p>{genre.name}</p>
                        </div>
                        <Link to = {`/movies/${id}`} className="btn btn-primary mb-3 width">
                            Change Image
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </article>
             );
        }
    }
}

export default MovieCard;
```

Aquí están mis rutas:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ToastContainer />
      <NavBar />
      <main className = "container">
          <Switch>
          <Route path = "/register" component = {RegisterForm} />
          <Route path = "/login" component = {LoginForm} />
          <Route path = "/movies/:id" component = {MovieForm} />
          <Route path = "/movies" component = {Movies} />
          <Route path = "/customers" component = {Customers} />
          <Route path = "/images" component = {Posters} />
          <Route path = "/not-found" component = {NotFound} />
          <Redirect from = "/" exact to = "/movies" />
          <Redirect to = "not-found" />
          </Switch>
      </main>
      <Footer />
   </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del *render* debía escribir este código para que funcione:

```js
const { title, movieImg, genre, _id } = this.props.movie;
```

Como se puede ver, la diferencia es que debía escribir `_id` en vez de `id` en el *object destructuring*.